# computing ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x)=x^3-ax^2-(a+3)x-1$, and let $\alpha$ be one of its roots, and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. It is easy to show that ${\rm Disc}(f)=(a^2+3a+9)^2$.

If $a^2+3a+9$ is square-free, then why should we have $D(f)=D(K)$?

> Could you please introduce me to a lemma or a theorem in some references?

If we have this, then $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ form an integral basis of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

There is no need to read the following texts.

---

---

---

I know how should I compute the ring of integers of the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{m})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{m})$ for a general case, but my solution uses localization techniques, and my solution to those cases is very long and bulky.

These are my best attempts about these special fields: Let $f(x)=x^3-ax^2-(a+3)x-1$, and let $\alpha=\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ be be its roots, and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. It is obvious that $f(\pm1)\neq0$, so it is irreduccible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $\{ i, j, k \} = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$, then
$$D = {\rm Disc}_K = ((\alpha_i-\alpha_j)(\alpha_i-\alpha_k)(\alpha_j-\alpha_k))^2 = (a^2+3a+9)^2 \in \mathbb{Q}^2,$$
and any transposition $(\alpha_i \mapsto \alpha_j, \alpha_j \mapsto \alpha_i, \alpha_k \mapsto \alpha_k)$, change the sign of $\sqrt{D} = (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)(\alpha_i-\alpha_k)(\alpha_j-\alpha_k)$, therefore the Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x)$ is isomorphic to the unique subgroup of order $3$ in $S_3$. Therefore the field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a cyclic Galois cubic field. At least one of the roots is real, and the two other roots can not be complex; Otherwise $K$ is not the splitting field of $f(x)$. So we can conclude that $r_1=3$, and $r_2=0$.